# Python Yield Statement does not appear to continue where it left off

Tags: python, yield

I must be overlooking the obvious, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why this yield statement does not continually give me a new datetime value that is 15 minutes later than the previous one.  The gettime function is behaving more like a function that "returns" rather than "yields".

```
import datetime

#function that continually adds 15 minutes to a datetime object
def gettime(caldate):
    while True:
        yield caldate
        caldate += datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)

#initialize a datetime object
nextdate = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 22, 11,0,0,0)

#call gettime function 25 times.
for i in range(0,25):
    print gettime(nextdate).next()


#output feels like it should be a series of incrementing datetime values 15 minutes apart.
#in actuality, the same result namely:

#2011-08-22 11:00:00

#happens 25 times.
```

Comment: The first comment in your code is misleading. Since you use the keyword `yield` this `def` block magically becomes a generator instead of a function, so you may wish to change the first word to "generator"

Answer (score 15):

It's because you're calling the generator each time, starting it anew.

Here is a fixed version:

```
dates = gettime(nextdate)
for i in range(0, 25):
    print dates.next()   # note that you're not initializing it each time here
                         # just calling next()
```

That gives me:

```
2011-08-22 11:00:00
2011-08-22 11:15:00
2011-08-22 11:30:00
2011-08-22 11:45:00
...etc.
```

An important thing to remember is that a function that `yield`s actually **returns a generator**, as you can see when we look at my `dates` object:

```
>>> dates
<generator object gettime at 0x02A05710>
```

This is what you can repeatedly call `next()` on to get the next value.  Each time you executed your loop, you were creating a *whole new generator* and getting the next (in this case, first) value out of it.

Comment: `.next()` is deprecated (It becomes `.__next__()` in Python3). You should prefer to use `next(dates)` if your version of Python is new enough to support it (2.6+)

Comment: you don't even need `next`. Just iterate it until you get enough amount of data.

Comment: @gnibbler true, though I was just modifying the original as little as possible to show where the real problem was

Answer (score 3):

Daniel already pointed out that you are creating a fresh generator each time through your loop. It is more usual to loop over a generator, or have another generator consume it, than to explicitly call `next()` every time.

Here is how you could loop over an islice() of your generator.

```
from itertools import islice
import datetime

#generator that continually adds 15 minutes to a datetime object
def gettime(caldate):
    while True:
        yield caldate
        caldate += datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)

#initialize a datetime object
nextdate = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 22, 11,0,0,0)

#call gettime function 25 times.
for the_date in islice(gettime(nextdate),0,25):
    print the_date
```

You can also simplify this to a generator expression if you wish

```
from itertools import islice, count
import datetime

#initialize a datetime object
nextdate = datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 22, 11,0,0,0)

#generator expression that continually adds 15 minutes to a datetime object
gettime = (nextdate+datetime.timedelta(minutes=15*i) for i in count())

#call gettime function 25 times.
for the_date in islice(gettime,0,25):
    print the_date
```

Comment: how is that relevant to the OP?

Comment: @Winston, how is showing how to loop over a generator _not_ relevant here. While `next()` is required sometimes, looping over a generator is the usual way to use them, and helps avoid the confusion between functions/generators

Comment: Oh, I see now. Sorry. Apparently I can't retract a downvote. But still, you didn't explain the point he's actually gotten wrong.

Comment: @Winston, fair enough. I didn't want to repeat Daniel's answer, but I felt that it was important to point out that using generators correctly can make your code simpler and easier to read. I think that by writing the code the "usual way", the confusion between function and generator is less likely to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Using print_function:

```
print(*[i[0] for i in zip(gettime(nextdate), range(25))], sep='\n')
```

But you may want to have just the list.